# When denoting a company name, followed by a strap line, what punctuation mark should I use?

Tags: punctuation

When writing out a company name, which would you use:

> Company Name: Strapline
>
> Company Name - Strapline
>
> Company Name – Strapline
>
> Company Name, Strapline

Or is the correct one missing from this list entirely?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: It's going to be put in the <title> tag of a website I'm building. It's what appears at the top of the window.

Comment: Shouldn't this be *tag line*? Or is *strap line* also an acceptable alternative?

Comment: @JimiOke I think their both interchangeable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Colon (:) or dash (—) is fine. Personally I find dashes easier to read in search engine result pages.

I recommend Jakob Nielsen's [Tagline Blues: What's the Site About?](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20010722.html) for advice on writing good strap lines.

Answer (score 1):

No hard and fast rule, really; whatever looks better. I would use a -:

> Acme - Making crazy stuff since 1932